# Get the Size of every function in a file

Tags: python, scipy, analytics, metrics

How would I find the size of every function in a file using python?

For context, I'm learning pyplot as well as scipy, and I wanted to measure the size of the functions in a programming file, and then measure the frequency of that size.

What I'm looking for is a way to read a file, identify a function, count the lines of the function, and then add it to a list, I don't really care if the function returns a list, I can always write a function that condenses the list of lists into one list.

**Example of what I'm trying to implement:**

```
Function A has a length of 10 lines
Function B has a length of 16 lines
Function C has a length of 8 lines
Function D has a length of 5 lines
```

Given the above data, I want to be able to condense that into a list of `[10,16,8,5]`.

Additionally: I'm going to be testing this on a couple of beginner C projects, and only want to test the files with the .c extension, not .h.
Code I have so far:

```
# Counts the number of lines in the file
def line_counter(file_name):
    tot_line = 0
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tot_line += 1
    return (tot_line)


# Counts the number of lines that end with a semicolon
def semi_counter(file_name):
    tot_semi = 0
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            sline = line.strip()
            if len(sline) > 0 and sline[-1] == ';':
                tot_semi += 1
    return (tot_semi)


# Returns the maximum nesting depth of the file
def max_depth(file_name):
    max_dep = 0
    dep = 0
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for ch in line:
                if ch == '{':
                    dep += 1
                if ch == '}':
                    dep -= 1
                if dep > max_dep:
                    max_dep = dep
    return max_dep


# Counts the number of characters in a file
def char_counter(file_name):
    tot_chars = 0
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tot_chars += len(line)
    return (tot_chars)


# Counts the number of comments in the file
def comm_counter(file_name):
    comm_chars = 0
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        block_comment = False
        for line in f:
            lch = None
            line_comment = False
            for ch in line:
                if lch == '/' and ch == '*':
                    block_comment = True
                if lch == '*' and ch == '/':
                    block_comment = False
                if lch == '/' and ch == '/':
                    line_comment = True
                lch = ch
                if line_comment or block_comment:
                    comm_chars += 1
    return comm_chars


# Counts the number of root level functions
def block_counter(file_name):
    block_tot = 0
    dep = 0
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for ch in line:
                if ch == '{':
                    dep += 1
                if ch == '}':
                    dep -= 1
                    if dep == 0:
                        block_tot += 1
    return block_tot
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Python has several ways of achieving what you want, even without third party libraries. Please share your code and be specific about what is causing you trouble, or where you're stuck.

Comment: You can read the file and count the number of lines between lines that begin with `def`

Comment: `Function.__code__` contains a few helpful variables. But the `inspect` library is usually to be preferred

Comment: @MagnusMarvik the OP want to analyze `.c`, not `.py`.